Lorentz ether theory (LET) vs special relativity
According to wiki LET page
“[Mansouri–Sexl] implies that a one-way speed of light experiment could in principle distinguish between LET and SR… In the absence of any way to experimentally distinguish between LET and SR, SR is widely preferred over LET”
In both (indistinguishable) theories two observers in different inertial reference frames will disagree on things like:

Frequency of given light
Order of events
Distances and time

Is according to LET the observers experience an “optical illusion” expect for the absolute reference frame?
Extending to gravity cases, in the absolute frame an object falling to black hole will take infinite time to reach the EH while finite from the falling object pov.
Isn’t that a contradiction for having such LET absolute “always right” reference frame?


Is according to LET the observers experience an “optical illusion” expect for the absolute reference frame?

Yes, but not an optical illusion like a trick of the brain. It is an optical effect in the sense that it is a physical effect due to the velocity through the aether, which is the medium for optics in LET.

Extending to gravity cases, in the absolute frame an object falling to black hole will take infinite time to reach the EH while finite from the falling object pov. Isn’t that a contradiction for having such LET absolute “always right” reference frame?

It is not clear how LET would be extended to gravity. In particular, black holes are a feature of GR and LET is equivalent to SR, not GR. The mainstream papers on LET stopped many decades ago, and modern papers on the topic are "fringe".

Seems that in any theory with absolute “Matrix” reference frame there will be a contradiction with GR in which for external observer (might be in the absolute frame) it will take infinite time for an object to fall into EH while also saying that it’s finite from object pov.
Are we sure that such GR outcome is correct? When measuring the time for object to fall into EH are we just talking about the time it will take the (outgoing) signals to reach the observer back or is it infinite regardless?

Maybe. But there is a pretty big gap between “seems that…” and “it can be proven that…” We are sure that such an outcome is the result of using the Schwarzschild coordinates. But we are free to use other coordinates that don’t go to infinity at the horizon.

Neither Lorentz Ether Theory nor special relativity deals with gravity, so as posed the question has no direct answer. You're right that the existence of gravitational time dilation poses a challenge for LET. It's probably not an insurmountable challenge. But as @Dale mentions, there isn't much research going on in Lorentz Ether Theory and it hasn't fully been extended to handle gravity. This is in contrast to the usual (geometric) interpretation of special relativity which has successfully been extended to the general theory of relativity, the current leading theory of gravity.
@Steve asserts in his answer that the lack of research on LET is for "ideological" reasons, but this is pretty much exactly backwards. Lorentz Ether Theory, in its original incarnation with a luminiferous ether, predicted relativistic effects like time dilation only for electromagnetic phenomena. We actually observe time dilation for nuclear processes (like muon decay) with no electromagnetic component. One can try to extend the ether in some way to incorporate the strong and weak nuclear forces, but given that the ether is then by construction completely unobservable (and possessed of extraordinary properties unlike any other medium) it becomes a superfluous element of the theory and should be discarded by Occam's Razor.
That's not to say that all research on ether theories has been or should be abandoned, and there are still papers that pop up from time to time, but they remain out of the mainstream of physics. I think LET is mainly popular among laymen and among philosophers who have an ideological attachment to presentism, which in its simplest form requires a preferred frame to provide a universal "now". But that's a whole other topic.

"possessed of extraordinary properties unlike any other medium" - I don't think that is what was at stake for Lorentz. The issue is finding a united description of wave mediums that applies both to the aether and any other medium. Gravity, incidentally, has its analogy in the "refractive index" of a medium, and that is how a Lorentzian explanation would proceed.

"We actually observe time dilation for nuclear processes (like muon decay) with no electromagnetic component." - which suggests that the Lorentzian approach would have to unify what are currently regarded as different things, and it would have to propose that nuclear processes like decay are caused (or the rate influenced) by something which is mediated at finite speed through the aether. Physics is otherwise pretty thin - bald, in fact - on explaining what causes an instance of decay.


Extending to gravity cases, in the absolute frame an object falling to black hole will take infinite time to reach the EH while finite from the falling object pov. Isn’t that a contradiction for having such LET absolute “always right” reference frame?

No I'm not quite sure this reasoning is consistent with Lorentzian tenets.
What exactly happens inside a black hole, or even what a black hole is, is not fully understood, and for now is the topic of partial theories.
On the Lorentzian approach generally
As @Dale already mentions, physicists largely abandoned exploring the Lorentzian approach a generation ago. This abandonment occurred basically due to the ideological preferences of physicists, rather than for scientific reasons.
This prolonged neglect is then usually used by the opponents of a Lorentzian approach to recursively justify less investigation or to imply that the visibly less substantial development is a sign of something other than the demonisation campaign towards it in the first place.
You see evidence of this in how @Dale speaks. He is right that "mainstream" papers largely stopped decades ago. He is probably right that papers now tend to be "fringe", since these papers will often be the product of pursuits by a small minority without institutional or collegiate support, perhaps even by non-professionals. So he can't be accused explicitly of telling lies. What he doesn't explicitly address however is why this situation prevails, and leaves the reader to surmise and speculate what might be going on. What is clear though, is that "mainstream physicists" are staying away from the topic.
To digress further for a moment and draw an analogy about how this tactic works, it's basically the same strategy of how the US embargoes Cuba to within an inch of its life and thus causes relative statis in the economic development of a small place, then insinuates the relative lack of economic development is caused by something other than their own embargo - perhaps, by the intrinsic character of their economic system.
In a black hole
What happens in an ordinary gravity well, is that physical activity closer to the centre of the well slow down relative to things away from the well. This is relatively speaking, but not subjectively speaking - it's objectively measurable to be the same fact in both places.
A naive subjective theory that equipment entering a well somehow causes the rest of the universe to speed up around it, is contradicted by the comparative ease of doing multiple experiments at once with different wells in different places, and observing that the change in speed seems to be localised in space and time to the equipment in each case moving toward or away from the relevant well, rather than the pace of the entire rest of the universe being influenced by (and that influence somehow centering around) the relative location of a small piece of man-made equipment.
What is seen from inside the well is that local activity appears to progress normally, whilst activity looking away to everywhere else in the universe (save for anything plunged into other gravity wells elsewhere) speeds up. The stronger the well, the more pronounced this effect becomes - it seems plausible to suggest that a human in a very strong gravity well, might in mere seconds of his own experience, see eons of events pass by everywhere else.
What's not clear is what happens when gravity intensifies to the hypothetical point that activity actually stops. It's not clear that it does so, rather than simply that the gravitational gradient becomes so extreme that the existing physical form of any matter is destroyed.
Lorentzian approach to event horizons
I assume the way the Lorentzian approach conceives a black hole is as being like a bubble in the medium, where eventually all things heading toward the bubble must crash-land onto the bubble surface and become integrated into the surface.
This reconciles with the notion of a "singularity" in the sense that this bubble in the medium will appear as some kind of strange point with no volume, when sounded-out using EM signals mediated by that medium, but it also suggests that the bubble is not in fact small but still cosmological in scale.
This is in-keeping with the Lorentzian approach overall where it generally proceeds from analogies of things that we already see can exist in the physical world at conventional scales. This is how relativity was developed in the first place, by proceeding from what was (imperfectly) known about other wave mediums.
Whereas opponents of the Lorentzian approach tend to prefer explanations where no analogy need be drawn with anything we already know, and where certain physics may have special explanatory concepts which need not be shown to apply to anything else but the one case.
Coming back to the central point of this, the Lorentzian approach proceeds from tenets in which what exists is not necessarily what you can currently see. It has good ground for this, because the physical signals that get mediated by a medium can be influenced independently by things which do not affect the source itself. Therefore, there is often a question about whether what is being seen is something local to the source or something local to the signal, or what the correspondence is between the condition of the source and the condition of the signal.
This is key to reconciling what you thought might be the contradiction, because what it can say is that the destruction of anything that falls in does occur in finite time, you just cannot observe the destruction happen from afar by any signal. That's consistent with it seeming to take an infinite amount of time for the destruction to happen, when you're waiting for the signal that it has happened. Outside, you will be waiting forever for a signal that will never arrive.

I think it's better to not resort to personal attacks like you did. What Dale said is objectively correct. Alternative gravitational and SR models are fringe. That is not in and of its itself an indictment on the research. It just means it isn't popular and isn't pursued by the community at large.

@CameronWilliams, I conceded what he said was correct. What I said he was remaining silent on, improperly so in the circumstances, is why the case prevails. It's not a casual oversight by him, because I'm already familiar with his views and I've already knocked him back on previous occasions from saying outright that Lorentz was falsified. He understands the issues, and he is still attempting to reproduce a denigratory attitude towards Lorentz, now by insinuation. Also Lorentzian approaches are not "alternative models", they are alternative derivations of the models we already have.

"Outside, you will be waiting forever for a signal that will never arrive" so the external observer just measures the time of the fallen object by signals it sends back?
The external observer can’t tell the time of the fallen object clock without getting such signals (e.g. just by calculations according to the metric)?

@RaniSharoni, you can calculate times in GR for ordinary gravity wells. The problem is accounting for the "event horizon" concept, where by definition the models we have predict there is no further signal and never again will be, and where you're potentially not just analysing something that is merely proceeding very slowly under heavy gravity, but is actually utterly destroyed in its existing form and torn asunder at the most fundamental level.

I don’t believe that I have ever said that LET was falsified. So “I've already knocked him back on previous occasions from saying outright that Lorentz was falsified” is simply untrue. I cannot be “knocked back” from a position that I do not hold. As you note, I am careful to make factual statements about LET. In fact, I am not even opposed to LET. I am opposed to assertions that any interpretation is true or correct, regardless of whether the assertion is pro-LET or pro-block universe. Both camps tend to misunderstand my actual position as opposition to their pet interpretation

@Dale, well I suppose we will leave the point in abeyance, since I am proceeding only from a vague recollection distant in time now. I do agree with you that nobody should go as far as to say a Lorentzian approach is "true or correct" - the issue for me is how often it is represented to be wrong and false. I should also add that a Lorentzian approach is not opposed to or inconsistent with the use of 4D geometry or the block-universe model, the dispute would be purely about whether the concepts of that model correspond directly to reality, that is, directly to things which exist or not.

@Steve I also disagree with representing LET as being wrong or false.  Indeed, the fact that the LET interpretation is consistent with the block universe interpretation is precisely the reason that I object to either assertion. I suspect that whatever disagreement you and I had was more subtle than this.
